# Best way to build a RTSP client on Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, rtsp

I'm looking for a way to make an RTSP client in Android. I just want to connect an app to an RTSP server and communicate to get stream (as a byte array/buffer, no decoding, no playback, nothing else than get the byte stream). So no all-in-one player suggestion or something else please, just an RTSP access client. I'm surprised that Android supports RTSP (see [Supported Media Format](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html#network)), but doesn't provide an API to manage RTSP access (or, I didn't find one??). So here you are my first question:

- Can I use Android's `MediaPlayer` API to connect an app to a RTSP server and get the byte received without decoding/playing it?

On the other side, I'm looking for a RTSP library/framework for Android (or in pure Java, but for Android usage). And second surprise: there is nothing! Or... a few things like libstreaming but it's no longer alive. So here is my second question:

- Is there an RTSP library (or just client library) available?

Third question:

- Can I use FFmpeg RTSP access to do that? And how? (do I need all FFmpeg dependencies?)

Thanks for advises

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, libstreaming is quite alive, and just recently has switched to Apache license.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FFmpeg or [Live555](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/) (used by VLC) are your best choices here. If you are really sure that you don't need to decode use Live555 since it would be more lightweight - have a look at their "openRTSP" example client that is bundled with the source code as an example, that should contain what you need to build an RTSP client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I finally decided to use FFmpeg because I already have this dependency in my project (I didn't tell it in my question, otherwise answers were "So use FFmpeg!" ^^).

Comment: I am trying to use ffmpeg on Android N and Android O, but it is not starting stream. Not sure what am I doing wrong. This is first time, I am trying to stream video via IP camera connected via my android WiFi hotspot. Also, the camera are generic cameras from market. I tried a lot of other forums to resolve issue, but no use. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: @N0un, how did you manage to include FFmpeg in an Android project?

Comment: @eskalera There is some different ways to do that, it depends mainly on your current project architecture : you can use the NDK, JNI, or the powerful JavaCPP library for example.